# Mirror shake emulation for the light

Tags: visible-light, photons, reflection

Is there any way to simulate mirror shaking? Final goal is to make send light beam to the mirror and get reflected beam the same, as it happens if mirror is vibrating. Mechanical vibration is limited and we cannot make it of course with very high frequency, like 1Ghz (10^9 hz).

Maybe there is a way how to make it with not mechanical vibration? For example, if I send via metal plate some electrical current (AC) with 1Ghz frequency will it make this effect that reflected light will be the same as reflected light from vibrating mirror?

I read some articles that some people did it to simulate mirror movement with 1/3 speed of light to turn vacuum photons to real ones, but I did not get how they made it.

For example here is explanation what they did
http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2011/nov/17/how-to-turn-darkness-into-light

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "reflected beam the same, as it happens if mirror is vibrating"? I don't understand why you would not get the same kind of light, and what differences you expect from a vibrating mirror.

Comment: Do you know about *acousto-optic* modulators?

Comment: @fffred I mean that due to doppler effect reflected light will have different frequency (modulation).

Comment: @ThePhoton I did not know about acousto-optic modulators. I will try to read. If you can give me good link, it will be very helpful.